# How can I install a library in a custom path as if I installed it by using apt?

Tags: apt, opencv

For example, if I want to install OpenCV library in a custom path, inside a secondary disk, which files I have to change, to have it linked as if it was installed in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: `/usr/local/` would be a good place,  but for a more in-depth answer, you should have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685874/9224859). Maybe this will help.

Comment: If you installed it by apt, it wouldn't be in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Thank you @RobertRiedl I will see the post you mentioned. I want to change the location to a secondary disk, out of the typical installation path in /usr.

Comment: well, just sym-link to it ? or is that not allowed with libraries ? `ln -s /mnt/second/disk/lib/ /usr/local/lib/special_libs`

Comment: I think that the problem is the linker @RobertRiedl

Comment: @RobertRiedl thank you, I will try to use a link and I will comment the results.